# how to use singleton firebase service on Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have 4 pages. I called `getRide()` method in every 4 pages. it's means 4 times database call. Am I right? Is it possible to create a singleton for this scenario?

**Firebase Service**:

```
class FirebaseService {
    final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;

    Stream<List<RideModel>> getRide() {
        return _db.collection('ride')
               .snapshots()
               .map((list) => list.documents.map((doc) => RideModel.fromFirestore(doc))
               .toList());
    }
}
```

**Calling Method**:

```
@override
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   db.getRide().listen(getRide);
}

void getRide(List<RideModel> model) {
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
       rideModel = model;
    });
}
```

I can't pass `rideModel` through Navigator. because when change data in ride collection need to change 4 pages UI.

Comment: You can use `Provider` which would contain the data that you want to display, when `Stream` gets new data you add it to `Provider` and in other 3 parts of your code, you can use `Consumer` to listen to those data. So, this way you only listen to stream just once.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Okay Thank you. add data like this `selectNotifier.value.add(productModel);` Right? Is my answer wrong for this?

Comment: Your model should have data in form of List<RideModel>. When data arrives in stream add that data to list by first getting reference to your provider using Provider.of and then accessing List and using .add on it. I'm on phone so can't help you much.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Okay. Thank you. I will try and let you know

Answer (score 1):

> Someone tells me this answer is correct for the above problem.

I found this way to solve this problem.

I used get_it package and create service locator,

```
GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;

void setupSingletons() async {
  locator.registerLazySingleton<FirebaseService>(() => FirebaseService());
}
```

And then added to the main class

```
void main() {
  setupSingletons();

  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: globalProviders,
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}
```

And every screen I added,

```
class _Screen1 extends State<Screen1> {
//  final db = FirebaseService();
  FirebaseService db = GetIt.I.get<FirebaseService>();
```